# Weblogic 12c: MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic

Error when starting weblogic 12c:
Full Stack log:

User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:276)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:661)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:648)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.getContextURLForPath(BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.getResources(BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1178)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:639)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: java.net.MalformedURLException: The path for getResource() must begin with a '/'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.getResource(WebAppServletContext.java:755)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.getContextURLForPath(BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.getResources(BaseWebConfigResourceProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1178)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$URITask.call(ConfigManager.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:639)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:185)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)

> 

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I have got this exception while deploying on weblogic and I don't know where can I find this path "without the '/'" thing

Comment: Then please show the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Full stack trace is included with the question

Comment: No, it's not. Please read it, before you post it: "Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace"